# How to create IEnumerable.ToString

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0, ienumerable

If I have an `IEnumerable`, is this my cleanest way to create a ToString method that spits out the values comma delimited?

```
   var enumOfObjects = myEnumerable as IList<object> ?? myEnumerable.Cast<object>().ToList();
   var enumOfStrings = enumOfObjects.Select(x => x.ToString());
   var finalString = String.Join(",", enumOfStrings);
```

Or, would a foreach loop be better? Or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You already answered your question, `String.Join` is simplest one

Comment: Side note: Reading this, it isn't immediately clear if `enumOfStrings` is an `enum` or an `IEnumerable`..

Comment: Maybe:    `string finalString = string.Join(",", myEnumerable.Select(x => x.ToString()));`

Comment: `String.Join(",", myEnumerable.Cast<object>())` may be better (avoiding `ToList` call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is shorter (and might be considered cleaner):

```
enumOfObjects.Aggregate((a,b) => a+","+b))
```

Looks something like:

```
IEnumerable<object> enumOfObjects = new List<object> {1, "Cat", 3, 4};
Console.WriteLine(enumOfObjects.Aggregate((a,b) => a+","+b));
//outputs 1,Cat,3,4
```

If you actually want to use it as a string you need to call `ToString()` on it or cast it to string.

Comment: Side note: If you want to go fancy with Aggregate please use `StringBuilder`... Also this answer does not show `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: Yah, that is actually what Resharper suggested. I just didnt think Aggregate is as obvious...but I guess mine isnt either...I will prob just do this and wrap it in an extension method

Comment: @JustinPihony I think the original way you did is good. Aggregate is very common in more functional languages (better known as 'reduce' or 'fold').

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like your code already works, you could make your code into a extension method for ease of reuse:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static string ToCommaSeparatedList(this IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        var enumOfObjects = myEnumerable as IList<object> ?? myEnumerable.Cast<object>().ToList();
        var enumOfStrings = enumOfObjects.Select(x => x.ToString());
        return String.Join(",", enumOfStrings);
    }
}
```

Then you can use the method a little bit more easily:

```
myEnumerable.ToCommaSeparatedList();
```

Comment: Not that it looks like question is about non-generic version of `IEnumerable` as `String.Join` already works fine with any generic on...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You're right.  I've changed the answer.  I really just meant that since OP already has something that works, but doesn't like that it is clunky, he could encapsulate it in an extension method.

Comment: Yah, I planned on doing that in the end, but was looking for the best thing in the extension method. If I am wrapping anything, then I am going to go with the Aggregate as it should be slightly more performant